Is storing firebase service-account-file,.json file as string in firestore & then retrieving in android app secure?
I am migrating from fcm legacy api to http v1. To get credentials I am using the following code snippet
String jsonString = "jsonFromServiceAccount";

InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream).createScoped(Lists.newArrayList(firebaseMessagingUrl));

Since I can't place the jsonString directly in my code I am storing the jsonString in firestore , then retrieving it in the application class, stored the string in a singleton & later using as necessary. My firestore security rules only allow authenticated users to perform read or write & I have enabled app check on firestore.
Now is the procedure safe? Also suppose someone have a rooted android device. Will they be able to ANYHOW get the string stored on jsonString or in singleton class variable? Is there any safer way through which I can get the credentials in my android app which will work in both development & production? Thanks.

Secure or safe are not absolute values. They only make sense if you specify what you want them to be safe/secure from.

Since you specify a rooted device, then indeed those users can see whatever values are in your code. But honestly, on Android devices they can often already see that anyway. If this is a concern, consider implementing App Check - which helps protect against that specific type of problem.

In general though, I strongly recommend against calling the FCM API directly from within the application that you share with your users. There is always a chance (since security is never absolute) that someone intercepts your credentials and at that point they can send whatever messages they want to any of your users. Heck, since you seem to be using a service account they can actually do anything they want with your project - it's like adding them as a collaborator to the project. 
In fact, the documentation on authorizing message sending starts with:

Requests sent to FCM from your app server or trusted environment must be authorized.

So you should only call this API from devices you can trust, such as your development machine, a server you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.

A typical way to then still allow you client to send messages to each other, is to implement your own server-side API that calls FCM, and that the client-side app can call. This way, your credentials live on the server, and your code on that server can ensure what messages can be sent to whom.
An example of this approach can be found in the Firebase documentation for Cloud Functions as Notify users when something interesting happens, which covers this scenario:

Even when your specific needs are different, this example provides a good starting point.
Also see my answer to How to send one to one message using Firebase Messaging

Suppose I am using a cloud function which uses firebase admin sdk to send notification. When a user likes another user a method sendNotification() get called and that method  invoke a function FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()                 .getHttpsCallable("sendMessageNotificationFunction")                 .call(sendMessageMap);. Now is this process is safer considering I haven't implemented app check for cloud functions. Also is invoking cloud function directly from android app's source code is a good or bad practice?

"good" or "bad" are again not absolute values. On the first point: the call to the API is now being made from code that you have written, so you control exactly what data is in sendMessageMap. You can still do that wrong of course, but that'd be your mistake instead of a malicious user's goal. --- Also see What should I do when someone answers my question?
